# How to get ways from OpenStreetMap which are NOT part of any relation?

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I'm trying to get ways which are NOT part of any relation, but I couldn't find any example for this kind of exclusion.

For example, running tracks...

Ways included in

```
relation['route'='running']
```

being downloaded in

```
way['leisure'~'track|stadium']['sport'='running']
```

as well, which results this

[image]

Both "W" ways are included in "R" relation, so I don't need for those separatedly.

Hope it's clear :)

Thanks for any help in advance!

Comment: Here's an example for this kind of query: http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Find_all_bus_stops_which_are_not_included_in_a_relation - please report back if you can't make any sense of it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helped, and at overpass-turbo it's working (after changing node parameters to way parameters, and some kind of auto correction for node output - screenshot: http://imgur.com/a/exdpu), but if I export the query, and try to use it programatically, I get error  message:

http://overpass.osm.rambler.ru/cgi/interpreter?data=[maxsize:1073741824][timeout:900];area['name'='Magyarország'];way(area)['leisure'~'track|stadium']['sport'='running']->.all;relation(bw.all);way(r);(.all;-._;);(._;>;);out meta;): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

Comment: With urlencode + original line breaks from overpass-turbo it works now!

Thank you very much again :)

Comment: ok great. btw: You can also answer your own question below and accept it.

Comment: Ok, I made an answer. Best wishes :)

Answer (score 1):

Node example at [OSM Wiki](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Overpass_API_by_Example#Find_all_bus_stops_which_are_not_included_in_a_relation) via [mmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45213092/how-to-get-ways-from-openstreetmap-which-are-not-part-of-any-relation?noredirect=1#comment77414116_45213092).

For ways just change a few things...

Orginal example:

```
area[name="Bonn"];
node(area)[highway=bus_stop]->.all;
rel(bn.all);
node(r);
( .all; - ._; );
out meta;
```

Working example for ways:

```
area[name="%areaname%"];    
    way
      ["%whatever%"~"%you%|%need%"]
      ["%to%"="%filter%"]
      (area)
      ->.all;
    relation(bw.all);
    way(r);
    (
      .all;
      -
      ._;
    );
    (
      ._;
      >;
    );
    out meta;
```